# Unable to access the meta data inside a data which is in JSON format using nodejs

Tags: node.js

New to nodejs. This might be a very basic question. 
I have fetched data from mongoDB which is in JSON format.
Please find the sample data below.

```
{ 
  index: 0,
  name: 'Matt Sweeney',
  color: '#FFFFFF',
  display: true,
  Age: '24’,
  Weight: '60’
}
```

I am trying to access and get the value of the meta data called "name" inside a JSON formatted data inside "doc" using nodejs. But unable to do so.
Please find the code below.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/TestDB';
    MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log("connected for select");

        var cursor = db.collection('TestCollection').find();
        cursor.each(function(err,doc){
            console.log(doc);
            var Athname = doc;

            console.log(JSON.parse(Athname).name);
        });
```

When I run the above code, I am getting the following error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

I even tried the below code but no luck. Ended up getting the same error.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost/TestDB';
        MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
            if(err) throw err
            console.log("connected for select");

            var cursor = db.collection('TestCollection').find();
            cursor.each(function(err,doc){
                console.log(doc);
                var Athname = JSON.parse(doc).name;

                console.log(Athname);
            });
```

When I tried this, I got the following error.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost/TestDB';
        MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
            if(err) throw err
            console.log("connected for select");

            var cursor = db.collection('TestCollection').find();
            cursor.each(function(err,doc){
                console.log(doc);
                var Athname = doc.name;

                console.log(Athname);
            });
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Could somebody please guide me in implementing this and let me know where the mistake is?

Comment: you cannot use `JSON.parse` on object, it has to be JSON string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same then you can also use .toArray function which results an array of data, you can you for or something to loop inside.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDB';

MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
  if(err) {
      throw err            
  } else {
      var testCollection = db.collection('testCollection');
      testCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
         if(err) {
            console.log(err);
         } else {
            console.log(data);
         }
      })        
   }    
});
```

This is working for me, i tried locally...

Comment: Thank u for your reply Prasanth. I tried to do that but no luck. It did not work. Is there any other option